# Pseudo recursive calls = stackoverflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2 service with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I'm following this book to do it: [ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Web API
Building a REST Service from Start to Finish](http://www.apress.com/9781430249771)

I have these two classes.

**User**:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

**Group**:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }
}
```

An `User` could have `Group`s, and a `Group` has `User`s as `Members`.

These two classes are my `Data.Models` and I use a `Mapper` class to 'translate' them as `Api.Models` with these two methods:

```
public Models.User CreateUser(Data.Models.User modelUser)
{
    if (modelUser == null)
        return null;

    Models.User user = new Models.User()
    {
        UserId = modelUser.UserId,
        UserName = modelUser.UserName
    };

    if (modelUser.Groups != null)
        user.Groups = modelUser.Groups
            .Select(CreateGroup)
            .ToList();
}

public Models.Group CreateGroup(Data.Models.Group modelGroup)
{
    if (modelGroup == null)
        return null;

    Models.Group group = new Models.Group
    {
        GroupId = modelGroup.GroupId,
        GroupName = modelGroup.GroupName
    };

    if (modelGroup.Members != null)
        group.Members = modelGroup.Members
            .Select(CreateUser)
            .ToList();

    return group;
}
```

As you can see in `Mapper` class, `CreateUser` method calls `CreateGroup` method, and `CreateGroup` method calls `CreateUser`.

In my case `user1` is member of `group1` and `group1` has `user1` as a member. So, I get this:

- On `CreateUser` for`user1` it will call `CreateGroup` for `group1`.
- On `CreateGroup` for `group1` it will call `CreateUser` for `user1`.
- And so on...

Any idea about how to avoid this infinite recursive calls?

A solution could be to remove navigation properties like `Groups` on `User`, or `Members` in `Group` class from `CreateUser` and `CreateGroup` methods.

Comment: just create empty user and group and then mutate both to include the other object in their collections - that's the OO/imperative way and it's fine in this case - for an immutable/functional approach you would need to ["tie the knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if I had read it in Klingon I would understand the same (is a joke, I don't speak Klingon :-)). I'm searching more information about tie the knot. Thanks.

Comment: no don't - it's indeed a bit of flapsy comment on my side - the problem is just that if you want to do something like this (mutual recursive definitions of something without mutating) it get's really tricky - just follow my first advise and create user and group and then add them to the mutual collections ;)

Comment: You have a cycle, so dont follow user/group that has already been dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two possible solutions (I can think of two but there can be more).

1. (**simple graph**) split both your mapper methods into two - first one to initialize simple properties (name, id) and the second one to initialize navigation properties. Then, in a place in your code where you call the mapper, write a little bit longer script that makes use of these new methods that initialize navigation properties from user to groups but **do not** call the other method (from groups to users) so that you will have a graph of users poiting to groups.
2. (**full graph**) add a *tail* parameter to each of your methods that represents a list of objects that have already been visited. Then, upon recursive call, check if the element is already in the list and **only** if it is not - add it and call recursively. This way, recursive calls will explore whole dependency graph between users and groups and will make sure no user and no group is processed more than once.